# Javascript does not fire

Tags: javascript

I have 2 versions of some javascript code below.

In version 1, when I call function `addNewCell(tableID)`, I am able to fire the line    `alert("bingo")`

In version 2, I added some more code. Now the line `alert("bingo")` does not fire. What gives? I did check and the parentheses balance out.

**version 1**

```
var counter = 1;
var limit = 100;


function isEven(value) {
    value = Number(value);
    if (value%2 == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}


function addNewCell(tableID){
     if (counter == limit)  {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding inputs");
     }
     else {
          alert("bingo");

    counter++;

        }
}
```

**version 2**

```
var counter = 1;
    var limit = 100;


    function isEven(value) {
            value = Number(value);
        if (value%2 == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }


    function addNewCell(tableID){
         if (counter == limit)  {
              alert("You have reached the limit of adding inputs");
         }
         else {
              alert("bingo");





            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            var lastRow = table.rows[rowCount-1];

            var lastRowCellsCount = lastRow.getElementsByTagName('td').length;
            // alternative var lastRowCellsCount = lastRow.cells.length;


           if isEven(lastRowCellsCount) {

                var newRow = table.insertRow(rowCount);
                var newCell0 = newRow.insertCell(0);

                newCell0.innerHTML = '<input type="text" size="76" onclick="addNewCell('initialTable')" name="myInputs[]">  <br><br>  <textarea rows="6" cols="76" name="myInputs[]"></textarea > ' ;




            }
          else {

             var newCell1 = lastRow.insertCell(1); 
             newCell1.innerHTML = '<input type="text" size="76" onclick="addNewCell('initialTable')" name="myInputs[]">  <br><br>  <textarea rows="6" cols="76" name="myInputs[]"></textarea > ' ;

            }

            counter++;

        }
}
```

Comment: Get any errors in your console?

Comment: Where do you initialize the `initialTable`?

Comment: @Hamish -- I'm trying to figure out how to use the console (Firebug or Chrome DevTools) -- if you could point me to a guide (that's easily understood by a noob), that would be sweet!

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+J on chrome, click the "console" tab.  now when you load a page, errors will show up.

Answer (score 4):

You have a syntax error in your string:

```
newCell0.innerHTML = '<input type="text" size="76" onclick="addNewCell('initialTable')" name="myInputs[]">  <br><br>  <textarea rows="6" cols="76" name="myInputs[]"></textarea > ';
```

will throw an `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

using `\` to scape the `''` will work:

```
 newCell0.innerHTML = '<input type="text" size="76" onclick="addNewCell(\'initialTable\')" name="myInputs[]">  <br><br>  <textarea rows="6" cols="76" name="myInputs[]"></textarea > ';
```

or, if you're trying to concatenate a variable (not defined in the code):

```
 newCell0.innerHTML = '<input type="text" size="76" onclick="addNewCell(' + initialTable +')" name="myInputs[]">  <br><br>  <textarea rows="6" cols="76" name="myInputs[]"></textarea > ';
```

As a plus, I suggest you take a look a [this link](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging) that shows you how to debug Javascript code in the Chrome DevTools (you can use firebug if you like)

Comment: @NicoSantangelo Thanks for your reply -- why should a syntax error matter? After all, if Javascript is being interpreted sequentially, even if there's a syntax error below, the alert("bingo") line should still fire, no?

Comment: This is not a `Runtime error` it's in the syntax, so the interpreter will catch it before running your code

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebug to view the console and you can see errors.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to use the console (Firebug or Chrome DevTools) -- if you could point me to a guide (that's easily digested by a noob), that would be sweet!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that instead of 
`if isEven(lastRowCellsCount)` 
I was supposed to use 
`if (isEven(lastRowCellsCount))` 
(i.e., I was missing the parentheses)